# How can I determine whether any checkbox is checked?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have some checkboxes in vb.net code.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxCreateAmendOrg" runat="server" Checked="False" Text="Create/Amend Organisation" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxCreateAmendCPUser" runat="server" Checked="False" Text="Create/Amend CP User" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxDeleteOrg" runat="server" Checked="False" Text="Delete Organisation" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxDeleteCPUser" runat="server" Checked="False" Text="Delete CP User" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to give alert to user if they have not selected atleast one. Can i have jquery code for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all the not checked checkboxes and check the length or size() of the jQuery object:

```
if ($('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0) {
  // some checkboxes not checked
}
```

Comment: But asp.net wraps checkboxes with span tag for css style. 
if ($('span > input ...

Comment: Yes, but this selector will look for all the checkboxes on the document.

Comment: it not checking and giving alert everytime whether check boxes are checked or not

Comment: it is checking all the checkboxes should be checked, but i want that user should check atleast one of them

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get it done...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// get all checked
var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox:checked");
if(checkboxes.size() == 0)
   alert("Please mark a checkbox!");

});
```

Comment: By accessing `checkboxes.attr("checked")` you are getting the *checked* attribute only of the first matched element...

Answer (score 0):

I advice use [jQuery Validation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate). It is very simple to use and so elegant (nice way to display error messages).
Check [that example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/). (There are two radio buttons which one should be checked.)

Answer (score 0):

The following code print an alert for each checkbox not flagged:

```
$("input:not(:checked)").each(function(){  
  alert( $(this).attr("id") + " isn't checked!" );
});
```

See also the [selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)